# jsf combined with file download servlet

Tags: jsf, servlets, download

I have two (independent) Projetcs:

**1.) JSF-WebApplication with many links**

```
<h:outputLink value="#{file.servletLinkWithParameters}">
     <h:outputText value="#{file.caption}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

**2.) Filedownload-Servlet, which returns me the file via attachment:**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
....

response.setContentType("application/force-download");
response.setContentLength(realFilesize);
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + realFilename);
final OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

URL url = new URL(realFilepath);
InputStream in = url.openStream();
final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int length;
while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
}
```

When I try to klick on the outputLink (e.g. url:8080/FileDownloadHandler/download?id=R0RcGAAD), it gives me "Unknown Adress".

**But when I open the same link in a new window or tab, it works fine.**

I don't know why...

Comment: what is the navigation url generated for `h:outputLink`?

Comment: http://serverIp:8080/FileDownloadHandler/download?id=R0RcGAAD. as mentioned, the link is OK. when I open it in a new window, it works. there has to be some depentencies with jsf...

Comment: I already solved it. the missing token was that I have not set a cookie which tells the script that the download request was processed correctly